# How to limit number of lines in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, limit, contenteditable

I have a `contenteditable` div and would like to limit to a maximum number of lines, using jQuery or JS.

**Edit 2:**
As it creates divs for new lines, how can I make it continue from the last line (limit - max line) when a text is pasted?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use jQuery to count the number of new divs created as line breaks inside your contenteditable div and remove the `contenteditable` property if this number reaches a given limit.

Note: This may not work with IE because as far as I know IE uses `<p>` for new lines.

HTML:

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">--- Insert text here ---</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("#test").on("keyup", function(){
        if ($("#test div").length > 5) {
            $("#test").prop("contenteditable" , false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My contenteditable attribute is of type 'plaintext-only', so it does not create divs, how to do in this case?

Comment: How should someone know about that if you don't provide any code?

Comment: btw, this is not supported or not known to be supported by the majority of browsers according to MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Sorry. I should have said but I really do not know how to do this.

Comment: Wow, I did not know that 'plaintext-only' was not supported by major browsers. I think I'm going to have to ask another question.

Comment: This is a very nice example to solve the stated issue, but as @HappyAnt pointed out, this does not work in all browsers. In fact, I could only get it to work in Microsoft Edge. I tried Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Internet Explorer. I even created a straight JavaScript version of it and got the same results... only worked in Edge.